# Gradle Clover Plugin for Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, clover

Has anyone tried to configure clover test coverage tool in Android Studio 1.0? 
I have tried using the gradle-clover-plugin https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-clover-plugin. But this is mainly for Groovy and not particularly on Java. Or did I misunderstood it? And how do I generate reports? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Atlassian Clover instruments both Groovy and Java, so the most probably gradle-clover-plugin too. Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA community edition, so it's possible to install Clover-for-IDEA there as well.

HOWEVER:

Atlassian Clover does **not** support Android platform (at the time I'm writing this post) and the Android platform is not on a short-term road map: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Clover+Road+Map

There is only an early alpha version for Eclipse available: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Clover-for-Android